javax.crypto.AEADBadTagException (BAD_DECRYPT) in AES256 decryption
I am trying to deal with large files in AES256 encryption/decryption with a string password, I am using the following classes to be able to hold the large files without OutofMemory errors:
class Encryptor {
    companion object {
        private const val SALT_LENGTH = 16
        private const val IV_LENGTH = 12
        private const val PBKDF_ALGORITHM = "PBKDF2WithHmacSHA256"
        private const val CIPHER_ALGORITHM = "AES/GCM/NoPadding"
        private const val KEY_LENGTH = 256
        private const val ITERATION_COUNT = 65536

        


        fun encryptUri(
            context: Context,
            inputUri: Uri,
            outputUri: Uri,
            password: String,
            progressListener: EncryptionProgressListener?,
            errorListener: EncryptionErrorListener?,
            successListener: EncryptionSuccessListener?
        ) {
            var bufferedInputStream: BufferedInputStream? = null
            var cipherOutputStream: ChunkedCipherOutputStream? = null
            val fileDescriptor = context.contentResolver.openFileDescriptor(inputUri, "r")
            val fileSize = fileDescriptor?.statSize ?: 0L
            fileDescriptor?.close()
            try {
                val inputStream = context.contentResolver.openInputStream(inputUri)
                bufferedInputStream = BufferedInputStream(inputStream)
                val salt = generateSalt()
                val secretKey = generateSecretKey(password, salt)
                val cipher = Cipher.getInstance(CIPHER_ALGORITHM)
                cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secretKey)

                val outputStream = context.contentResolver.openOutputStream(outputUri)
                outputStream?.write(salt) // Write salt to output file
                outputStream?.write(cipher.iv) // Write IV to output file

                cipherOutputStream = outputStream?.let { ChunkedCipherOutputStream(it, cipher) }

                val buffer = ByteArray(4096) // Reduce buffer size
                var bytesRead: Int
                var totalBytesRead = 0L
                while (bufferedInputStream.read(buffer).also { bytesRead = it } != -1) {
                    cipherOutputStream?.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead)
                    totalBytesRead += bytesRead.toLong()
                    val progress = if (fileSize > 0) {
                        ((totalBytesRead.toDouble() / fileSize.toDouble()) * 100).toInt()
                    } else {
                        0
                    }
                    progressListener?.onProgress(progress)
                }
                successListener?.onSuccess()
            } catch (e: Exception) {
                errorListener?.onError("Encryption error: ${e.message}")
                e.printStackTrace()
            } finally {
                bufferedInputStream?.close()
                cipherOutputStream?.close()
            }
        }


        fun decryptUri(
            context: Context,
            inputUri: Uri,
            outputUri: Uri,
            password: String,
            progressListener: EncryptionProgressListener?,
            errorListener: EncryptionErrorListener?,
            successListener: EncryptionSuccessListener?
        ) {
            var bufferedInputStream: BufferedInputStream? = null
            var cipherInputStream: CipherInputStream? = null
            val fileDescriptor = context.contentResolver.openFileDescriptor(inputUri, "r")
            val fileSize = fileDescriptor?.statSize ?: 0L
            fileDescriptor?.close()
            try {
                val inputStream = context.contentResolver.openInputStream(inputUri)
                bufferedInputStream = BufferedInputStream(inputStream)
                val salt = ByteArray(SALT_LENGTH)
                val iv = ByteArray(IV_LENGTH)
                bufferedInputStream.read(salt) // Read salt from input file
                bufferedInputStream.read(iv) // Read IV from input file

                val secretKey = generateSecretKey(password, salt)
                val cipher = Cipher.getInstance(CIPHER_ALGORITHM)
                val params = GCMParameterSpec(128, iv)
                cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, secretKey, params)

                cipherInputStream = CipherInputStream(bufferedInputStream, cipher)

                val outputStream = context.contentResolver.openOutputStream(outputUri)

                val buffer = ByteArray(4096) // Reduce buffer size
                var bytesRead: Int
                var totalBytesRead = 0L
                while (cipherInputStream.read(buffer).also { bytesRead = it } != -1) {
                    outputStream?.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead)
                    totalBytesRead += bytesRead.toLong()
                    val progress = if (fileSize > 0) {
                        ((totalBytesRead.toDouble() / fileSize.toDouble()) * 100).toInt()
                    } else {
                        0
                    }
                    progressListener?.onProgress(progress)
                }
                successListener?.onSuccess()
            } catch (e: Exception) {
                errorListener?.onError("Decryption error: ${e.message}")
                e.printStackTrace()
            } finally {
                bufferedInputStream?.close()
                cipherInputStream?.close()
            }
        }

        private fun generateSalt(): ByteArray {
            val salt = ByteArray(SALT_LENGTH)
            val random = SecureRandom()
            random.nextBytes(salt)
            return salt
        }

        private fun generateSecretKey(password: String, salt: ByteArray): SecretKey {
            val spec = PBEKeySpec(password.toCharArray(), salt, ITERATION_COUNT, KEY_LENGTH)
            val factory = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance(PBKDF_ALGORITHM)
            return SecretKeySpec(factory.generateSecret(spec).encoded, "AES")
        }
    }
}

ChunkedCipherOutputStream.kt:

class ChunkedCipherOutputStream(
    out: OutputStream,
    private val cipher: Cipher
) : FilterOutputStream(out) {

    override fun write(b: Int) {
        write(byteArrayOf(b.toByte()))
    }

    override fun write(b: ByteArray) {
        write(b, 0, b.size)
    }

    override fun write(b: ByteArray, off: Int, len: Int) {
        val output = cipher.update(b, off, len)
        if (output != null) {
            out.write(output)
        }
    }

    fun doFinal() {
        try {
            val output = cipher.doFinal()
            if (output != null) {
                out.write(output)
            }
        } catch (ex: IllegalBlockSizeException) {
            throw IOException(ex)
        } catch (ex: BadPaddingException) {
            throw IOException(ex)
        }
    }

    override fun close() {
        super.close()
    }
}

The encryptUri() works as expected but I am getting javax.crypto.AEADBadTagException: error:1e000065:Cipher functions:OPENSSL_internal:BAD_DECRYPT when trying to decryptUri() the same file with the same string password on the same device, what could be the issue here?

You forgot to initialize the cipher properly. For GCM you have to provide an additional GCMParameterSpec containing the unique nonce (for GCm the combination of key + nonce can only be used exactly one time, otherwise the crypto has to be considered broken).  BTW: Java already has an CipherOutputStream isn't that also usable in Kotlin?

Thanks @Robert, for the CipherOutputStream I am getting OutOfMemoryError in javax.crypto.CipherOutputStream.close in javax.crypto.Cipher.doFinal

As far as I can tell, ChunkedArrayOutputStream does nothing to mitigate the problems of using large files with GCM mode. Using GCM mode with large files is not going to work without substantial and painful work arounds to avoid the OutOfMemory errors.

You are right, I did more adjustments in ChunkedArrayOutputStream later, but The issue mentioned above occurs even with the dummy one too and you addressed the issue
